# sql dynamic where clause repeated column filter

Tags: sql, filtering

So I have been trying to research a way where I can have a stored proc that will perform dynamic search on various columns to filter the data, but has the capability of something similar to WHERE IN, i.e. to take multiple input criterion per column.

So let's say I have 3 columns FN, LN, DOB. I need to have a stored proc that will let me provide values for the any combination of the three variables with multiple values for each column.

EX: FN IN ('ADAM', 'BRIAN') OR LN IN ('SMITH') OR DOB is not provided.

I was trying to follow this,

```
SELECT 
  FN,    
  LN
FROM TestData
WHERE 
  (CASE 
    WHEN @FN IS NULL THEN 'True'
    ELSE FN
  END) = (CASE 
           WHEN @FN IS NULL THEN 'True'
           ELSE @FN
         END)
  AND (CASE 
        WHEN @LN IS NULL THEN 'True'
        ELSE LN
       END) = (CASE 
                WHEN @LN IS NULL THEN 'True'
                ELSE @LN
               END)
  AND (CASE 
        WHEN @DOB IS NULL THEN '1/1/0001'
        ELSE DOB
       END) = (CASE 
                WHEN @DOB IS NULL THEN '1/1/0001'
                ELSE @DOB
              END)
```

Comment: What database server do you use?

Comment: SQL. I think I have to pass an array of filter criteria to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got, it takes in three inputs and returns the columns for the values entered and omits the columns with Nulls. The comments are for testing the output since I don't have your tables.

```
Create  Proc TestProc (@LN Nvarchar(100), @FN Nvarchar(100), @DOB Nvarchar(100)) 
As
--      TestProc    '''Hello''', '''What'',''Hmmm''', Null

Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max),
        @Columns Nvarchar(Max) = '',
        @OrCriteria Nvarchar(Max) = '';        

If      @LN Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @Columns = @Columns + 'LN, ';
End;         

If      @FN Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @Columns = @Columns + 'FN, ';
End;     

If      @DOB Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @Columns = @Columns + 'DOB, ';
End;     

Select  @OrCriteria = Coalesce(@OrCriteria + ' Or ','') + varType + ' In (' + varVal + ')' 
From   (Select  'LN' As varType, @LN As varVal
        Union
        Select  'FN', @FN
        Union
        Select  'DOB', @DOB) As n

If      @Columns <> ''
Begin
        Set     @SQL = 'Select  ' + Left(RTrim(@Columns),Len(RTrim(@Columns))-1) + '
                        From    TestData 
                        Where   (' + @OrCriteria + ')';

        Select  @SQL
        --  Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL;                     
End
Else
Begin
        Return;
End;
```

Comment: If you copy and paste, create the sproc and run the test execution at the top you can see the output though, right? Is that output what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using SQLServer (my guess based on `@` variable prefix), so instead of passing scalar variables, you can pass a variable of `TABLE` type; thus, you can implement required logic in `JOIN` conditions. 
For instance,

```
CREATE TYPE MY_TABLE AS TABLE(FN varchar(20), LN varchar(20),DOB datetime2);
CREATE PROCEDURE foo (@tab1 MY_TABLE READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT d.*
  FROM TestData d
  INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @tab1) a 
 ON (
  a.DOB IS NULL OR a.DOB = d.DOB) -- just for example, I'm not sure I got all 
  --your requirements
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some general Oracle example. This will not answer your question but may give you some ideas:

```
-- Case in Where clause --
SELECT empno, ename, job
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE (CASE WHEN job = 'MANAGER' THEN '1'  
             WHEN job = 'CLERK'   THEN '2' 
        ELSE '0'  END) IN (1, 2) 
 /
```

More examples here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/oracle-sql-case-in-a-where-clause